# How to use laravel and angularjs routing together?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using laravel php framework for the code execution and I want angularjs to handle the routing for me. I have an example here : http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/preview which shows me how to swap between the pages using angularjs routing methods but they use simple .html files to render the content . It is a sample I found on the internet.

Moreover in laravel it has its own routes. How can i guide the angularjs router to call the laravel route and render the page accordingly after fetching the contents from database ? I am new to Angularjs . Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Laravel a an API provider (and so requesting it via REST) or do you want Laravel to render your pages with its templating system ?

Comment: what would you suggest.  I am confused here. I just want to use angluar js so that when you click on any links it should not reload the page. and render the content in d ng-view

Comment: You want to develop your frontend application with AngularJS, I get it. But how are you using Laravel ? Put Angular inside your Laravel view (I hope not, it's a very bad idea) ?

Comment: yea i guess. i am making a master.blade.php file which i render using the laravel route and in that i am tryng to manage the routes to different parts of site. Thing is when i use angularjs routing i see that there is a templateurl: thing which redirects generally to a .html file. but i want it to render a absolute URL which would be of a laravel page and just render it inside the ng view.

Comment: You can't use AngularJS inside of Blade, it's not designed to be used like this. You have to separate your Laravel application from you Angular application and make them communicate via REST API (for example).

Comment: ok thank you. Well how do i achieve that. do you have an example or anything which can guide me in the right direction...how do I seperate the two.

Comment: Google is your friend, there is plenty of articles covering this topic.

Comment: Well thank you . I have a few demos on google however If I face any issues then would post here. You have been of great help my friend..

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of methods achieving the goal, but you do NOT use blade any more. Here I am just explaining the easiest way.

1. create a index.php (not index.blade.php), in your routes.php, you have:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

It will return you the index page. 

In index.php, please include

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>
```

or your local dependencies.

2. In the public folder, you can create folder called "js", another folder called "templates".
3. In the "js" file, creates your "app.js", "controller.js", and etc. (Don't forget to include them in your index.php)
4. In the "templates" folder, you will create your template html. In your given example, they are "home.html", "about.html", "contact.html"
5. In the index page, you do the angular routing here. 

      app.js:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
               templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
               controller  : 'mainController'
           })

           .when('/about', {
               templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
               controller  : 'aboutController'
           })

           .when('/contact', {
               templateUrl : 'templates/contact.html',
               controller  : 'contactController'
           });
   });
   ```

Comment: so this means , that all request will be send to default prefix page, and then angular will handle it ? cause if u use angular router on another common html page if i pass an angular route directo to search browser it gives me a 404 error