# Angular js routing not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to setup simple angular routing with my Laravel application

```
import Angular from 'angular';
import Route from  'angular-route';
var route = Angular.module("main",[Route]);


route.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'app/test.html',
        activetab:'emp',
        controller:'WelcomeController'
    })
}]);

route.controller('WelcomeController',function ($scope) {
    alert('ok');
})
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="main" >

    <a href="#test">test</a>

</body>
```

When i click on the link i got nothing in browser there is no error present in console

Here is the url obtained when cliked on the link

```
http://localhost:8000/#!#test
```

**UPDATE**

Finally my routes works fine when i change to `div`

```
 <div id="main">
    <a href="#test">test</a>

     </div>
```

but the template file is not loading

Comment: Change `<a href="#test">test</a>` to `<a href="/test">test</a>`, and retry.

Comment: @31piy it conflicts with laravel routes

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: No error is shown that makes me annoying:)

Comment: template file location   `public/app/test.html`  and js file is in  public/app/js

Comment: did you try, <a href="#!/test"></a>, not sure why you have `#test` as href.

Comment: yep tried but got the same error

Comment: perhaps this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345421/how-to-use-laravel-and-angularjs-routing-together, your angularjs should be separate from your blade template that's probably why you're having a Laravel and AngularJS routing conflict.

Comment: I've refereed these question also,but still get blank page

Comment: One more thing i've removed angular route js file from my html but still there is no error message in console

Comment: and your template isn't blank? btw you need <div ng-view></div> in your `body` tag if you're doing SPA otherwise it wouldn't know where to load the page.

Comment: @MrNew thanks for points out the issue now everything solved its the problem with webpack build

Comment: @Jabaa glad its working now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145761/discussion-between-jabaa-and-mrnew).

Answer (score 0):

Change

From

```
var route = Angular.module("main",[Route]);
```

To

```
var route = Angular.module("main",['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Nop still the same error,i am using webpack to build the files

Comment: When i hide `import  'angular-route'` i got route not defined error

Comment: Try changing your template  <header>
        <h1>My app</h1>
        <ul>
           <a href="#test">test</a>       
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

Comment: could you more specific??

Comment: change your html as mentioned above